# PhpStorm unsuspended breakpoint never hit

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, breakpoints

When i set a suspending breakpoint in PhpStorm, it stops the program, thus the connection to xdebug and apache seems to work fine.

Yet, when i make the breakpoint unsuspending and check the "log Breakpoint hit" box, i never get to see the log output, unless a suspending breakpoint is hit later on.

My idea is to print the value of an iteration variable through an unsuspending breakpoint on every iteration, so i can see the progress of a for-loop in my debugger.
But since the debug windows doesn't pop up, i never get to see the debugger console unless a suspending breakpoint is hit.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion totally makes sense, the reason why it doesn't work is this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6178

Comment: is there any chance this gets fixed?

Comment: Not really planned for any release nearby, sorry.